# How do I use argument variables in a for loop for a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script

been struggling with this all day. So I have a script that looks something like this.

The terminal command would be something along the lines of

```
script.sh ARG1 ARG2 ARG3 ARG4
```

The script looks as follows:

```
totalargs=$#

for ((i=2; i<=totalargs; i+=2)); do
   curl somewebsite.com | grep "$i"
done
```

What I am trying to achieve is to grep every other argument however I can't seem to get the argument into the loop using $i. Which should be 2 then 4 in the provided case as the loop iterates.

Any ideas? Pretty new to bash scripts so any guidance is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It should work. Are you sure `curl` returns what you think it does? Try running the script under `set -xv`.

Comment: @choroba I know that the curl is returning what I want because when I hardcode the $i in the loop, I get the expected result. I tried running it with set -xv and couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: Why just every even argument? What are the odd ones used for?

Comment: @ilkkachu The even arguments are used elsewhere to process fields in my curl url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bash, you can use *variable indirection*

```
for((i=2;i<=$#;i+=2)); do echo "${!i}"; done
```

POSIXly, you could do something like

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do 
  echo "$2"
  shift; shift
done
```

However it's rather inefficient to call `curl` and `grep` once for every argument - I'd suggest revising your approach to the problem.

Comment: That worked for me, what does the exclamation mark in ${!i} represent?

Comment: @Safder see for example [What is indirect expansion? What does ${!var*} mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515411/what-is-indirect-expansion-what-does-var-mean)

Comment: Awesome, got it now!